# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: Why Doesn't the Integral Depend on Lower Bound?

Tags: calculus, integration

The second part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus essentially states that if $$F(x) = \int^x_a{f(t)}\,dt\,,$$ then $$F'(x) = f(x)\,.$$ My question is: why does the result not depend on the lower limit of integration $a$?

Comment: Novice guess here, but if $a$ is a constant, is $f(a)$ just absorbed into the constant of integration?  And regardless of what it was, it would disappear upon differentiation?

Comment: You already defined F(x) in terms of the integral with its lower bound anyways

Comment: An excellent answer has been provided.

Comment: a is a starting point and is a fixed constant ... flip the question around and ask yourself, why should it matter?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let, e.g., $b<a$. Then 
$$
G(x) := \int^x_b{f(t)}\,dt=\int_b^a {f(t)}\,dt+\int_a^x {f(t)}\,dt=F(x)+D,
$$
and the derivatives of $F$ and $G$ are identical.

Comment: Nice, succinct. +1.